# Unable to save changes to database via Entity Framework 6, have tried a few different totorials but none work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have tried following a few different tutorials to save updated date to my SQL Database but each fails to save and each one gives different errors, so I am at a complete loss on how I am supposed to update the data. These are what I have tried and the errors I get:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756368.aspx `context.UpdateObject` does not exist

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view Give the error

> System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException
>   : 
>   Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=619 give me the error:

> Sequence contains no elements

So I am at a loss as what I am supposed to do to update this date. Here are the two code blocks I tried:

```
[Route("Edit"), HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditSection([Bind(Include = "ID, RouteName, Type, Title, Synopsis")]  Section section, HttpPostedFileBase Logo)
{
    SectionAddEditVM model = new SectionAddEditVM { Section = section };

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            using (db)
            {
                var SectionUpdate = (from s in db.Sections
                                     where s.ID == section.ID
                                     select s).First();
                SectionUpdate.RouteName = section.RouteName;
                SectionUpdate.Type = section.Type;
                SectionUpdate.Title = section.Title;
                SectionUpdate.Synopsis = section.Synopsis;

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            ModelState.AddModelError("Processing Error", "There was a problem processing the change, please try again later.");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

AND

```
[Route("Edit"), HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditSection([Bind(Include = "ID, RouteName, Type, Title, Synopsis")] Section section, HttpPostedFileBase Logo)
{
    SectionAddEditVM model = new SectionAddEditVM { Section = section };

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            using (db)
            {
                db.Entry(section).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            ModelState.AddModelError("Processing Error", "There was a problem processing the change, please try again later.");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

About 200 lines above the edit code I have declared my `db` property using `private SectionContext db = new SectionContext();` and it is being used with no issues to add new data to the server and to get data from that server.

Comment: On the lines that read `using (db)`, that is where you normally create your database context - for example, `using (var db = new YourDatabaseEntities())`. I'm surprised that you're not getting a `NullReferenceException` when trying to use the `db` variable after that. Where is the `db` variable/field defined and initialized?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that DB is initialized about 200 lines up in the controller and it is used with no problems on saving new data and retrieving existing data.

Comment: If you initialize db variable elsewhere you should not use it in using() statement. using will close your db connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution just came to me, I realized on my view there was no input holding the ID of the section being edited so when it tries to check the DB it has no data to compare to the primary key on. I simply added: `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Section.ID)` and now it all works using:

```
using (db)
{
    db.Entry(section).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I am almost sure the id is a part of your url. If this is so, all you'd have to do is to have the `int? id` among your method parameters.

Comment: You're still using `using` incorrectly. When the block exits, `db.Dispose()` is being automatically called by the run-time. This *will* close your connection. If you happen to be re-initializing it somewhere else between every use, that's kind of smelly... You should initialize it at the `using` statement.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is can you be a bit more specific on the downfalls of what I am doing then "smelly"?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and adding a line to my input form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SectionID, model.SectionID)
```

Along with adding to the Bind in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "SectionID, SectionName, Note")]Section sectionObject)
{
    ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is my specific solution, I'm using EF 6.x.x with Sql Server and the table I'm trying to INSERT to has an **INSTEAD OF trigger** that messed up the TSQL command sent by the application, with SQL Server profiler found the following command.

Also keep in mind **RowId** is the name of the Identity Column on the table.

```
EXEC sp_executesql 
     N'INSERT dbo.TableName(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) 
        VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8)
        SELECT RowId
        FROM dbo.TableName
        WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND RowId = scope_identity()',
              N'@0 bigint,@1 decimal(8,3),@2 decimal(8,3),@3 varchar(50),
              @4 varchar(80), @5 decimal(11,2),@6 datetime2(7),
              @7 datetime2(7),@8 decimal(8,3)',
@0 = 1, @1 = 2, @2 = 3, @3 = 'a', @4 = 'b', @5 = 4, @6 = 'date', @7 = 'date', @8 = 5;
```

That was returning 0 records which caused the problem... so my fix was to modify the trigger, by adding the following Select statement to the trigger, right after the Insert statement.

```
SELECT
  RowId
FROM
  TableName
WHERE
@@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND
RowId= SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Hope this helps someone else, as I was down the VStudio path and my solution was on the DB side.

Answer (score -4):

The problem that Steve is having with your:

```
    using(db)
    {
    // Do something with the connection
    ...
    }
```

is that you should be initializing the db in the using.  For example if you want to use input from a file:

```
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(uploadedFile.InputStream))
    {
    // Do something with the connection
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    ...
    }
```

That way when you drop out of the loop the StreamReader is closed.